# map DTO to entity Model

Tags: dictionary, metadata, dto, entity-framework-6

I Have a MVC 5 web-based project. I am using ado entity model Database first with EF6.
From my model I have the following T4 generated Classes

```
namespace Mvc5.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Department
    {
        public Department()
        {
            this.Employee2 = new HashSet<Employee2>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee2> Employee2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Mvc5.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee2
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}

And I have a DTO Class not Mapped to Model

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Mvc5.Models
{
    public class DepartmentTotals
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Totals { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my Controller called employee I have a method EmployeesByDepartment/
which will return a view of Employees by the Departments

```
public ActionResult EmployeesByDepartment()
{
    var departmentTotals = db.Employee2.Include("Department")
                                       .GroupBy(x => x.Department.Name)
                                       .Select(y => new DepartmentTotals
                                       {
                                           Name = y.Key,
                                           Totals = y.Count()
                                       }).ToList();
    return View(departmentTotals);
}
```

The problem is when I try to add a strongly type view of this method using DepartmentTotals as Model

I get the following error

`Error: There was an error running the selected code generator
Unable to retrieve metadata for DepartmentTotals`

How do I map Department totals As data transfer object do I need to stop t4 generation or use the legacy object. So I can query the database  model using this DTO

Comment: When do you get exception? Is it when the query is executed, when view is rendered or when you actually try to add new view to your project? The last situation doesn't have anything to do with EF - it is more about tools for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: When I try to render The view.  I believe the only way to overcome this is to use Legacy object instead of T4 template So I just added the DTO as a model enity.